# using jquery to read json file

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to read a json file using the getJSON function in jquery, I haven't done this before I would just like to get the data to appear on my webpage

here is my code

```
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&callback=?" ; 
$.getJSON(url, function(res) {
    $('#result').html('<p>lon: ' + res.lon + '</p>');
```

});

here is my json file

```
{"coord":
 {
  "lon":-0.12574,
  "lat":51.50853
 },
 "sys":
 {
  "country":"GB",
      "sunrise":1380780339,
      "sunset":1380821577
     },
 "weather":
[{
  "id":521,
      "main":"Rain",
      "description":"proximity shower rain",
      "icon":"09n"
     }],
 "base":"gdps stations",
 "main":
   {
     "temp":290.43,
     "pressure":1008,
     "humidity":88,
     "temp_min":289.15,
     "temp_max":291.48
    },
"wind":
   {
     "speed":3.1,
     "deg":140
    },
"rain":
   {
     "1h":1.65
   },
"clouds":
     {
      "all":40
     },
"dt":1380823503,
"id":2643743,
"name":"London",
"cod":200
     }
```

Comment: Are you getting a CORS error when you try to load it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be **`city.coord.lon`** :

```
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&callback=?" ; 

$.getJSON(url, function(res) {
    $('#result').html('<p>lon: ' + res.city.coord.lon + '</p>');          
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Da2bq/)

Comment: works but what does the city pat mean I can't see it in the json file?

Comment: Then you're not looking closely enough, cause it's there.

Comment: got it example not the same as the URI

Answer (score 0):

The following URL:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&callback=?

prepends a `?` to the JSON output.

If you remove the `callback` parameter from the URL string. You should be able to read the JSON Object.

Comment: Not if it's a cross domain request that isn't using CORS